# Imagick on Symfony - attempted to load class Imagick from global namespace

Tags: php, symfony, imagick, shopware

I'm trying to use Imagick in Symfony (Shopware). When I instantiate a new Imagick-object in a Controller by writing

```
$image = new \Imagick();
```

it will give me following http-Response:

```
"Attempted to load class \u0022Imagick\u0022 from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a \u0022use\u0022 statement?"
```

Full http-response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"0","status":"500","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Attempted to load class \u0022Imagick\u0022 from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a \u0022use\u0022 statement?","meta":{"trace":[{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php","line":156,"function":"createImage","class":"ImageGenerator\\Controller\\ImageController","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php","line":78,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Kernel.php","line":199,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/SubRequestHandler.php","line":85,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":479,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\SubRequestHandler","type":"::"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":452,"function":"forward","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":346,"function":"fetch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":224,"function":"lookup","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php","line":178,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php","line":81,"function":"doHandle","class":"Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/public\/index.php","line":77,"function":"handle","class":"Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"}],"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/ImageGenerator\/src\/Controller\/ImageController.php","line":42}}]}
```

I'm using Shopware as a Docker Container (dockware / Ubuntu) and have installed the Imagick-extension via:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-imagick
```

Then enabled the extension in /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini by adding

```
extension=imagick
```

alternatively trying to specify the fully qualified path

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so
```

Then I restarted the apache server.

But when I run the app, it gives me the aforementioned error.

There are several PHP versions installed in the dockware image - but I checked the used version by displaying phpversion(). So it should be installed on the correct version. I've also installed it on all the other versions of Shopwares dependencies though.

Would appreciate if you guys know what could cause this issue. I'm fairly new to web development, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see imagick with phpinfo() ? May be try to add the extension in the php.ini of cli and apache too.

Comment: Grep your error log for `imagick.so` - the loading process might fail.